# cordova.file is undefined

Tags: cordova

I've installed the file plugin:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file
```

then

```
$(document).on('deviceready', function() {
    console.log(cordova.file);
});
```

prints "undefined" on any platform.

Cordova - 4.1.2, File plugin - 1.3.1.

Please help.

Comment: did you rebuild your project? `cordova platform build android`

Comment: previous comment makes sence (shouldn't it be `cordova build android` or `cordova prepare android`?) if you run your app from eclipse or xcode and not using the CLI (but be carefull, in that case runing this command will overwrite the content of the www folder in the platforms folder with the content of the root www folder.

Comment: It was a WP issue, on Android it is OK.
Will look back to WP soon.